# How can an LCD display show white pixels?

Tags: polarization

I have an LCD display that when I turn it on, the pixels are white.But as I know, an LCD display polarizes the light in the pixels and doesn't let the light to pass through.So , shouldn't the pixels be black as they are on most LCD displays?
Also my LCD display has a white LED blacklight.
[image: The LCD display]

Comment: So why can't the display be designed to polarize the light and _block_ it when actively polarized?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but those alpha-numerics don't look white.

Comment: If you un-cross the two polarisers. the pixels they let the light through. Cross them and it's black. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display#Overview